# Power duration curve for endurance sports

Tags: cardio, endurance, power, anaerobic, performance

I have a question regarding the power-duration curve for sports. This curve is power on the y-axis and time on the x-axis. For probably all endurance athletes they will have a exponential declining curve. Simply more power at lower durations. I suspect that this curve could be a great tool for determining deficiencies in aerobic or anaerobic performance. However this would be much easier to see and detect with a linear curve. With biking, rowing or similar you can just measure the power (watts) during a test and convert, using total energy expenditure (power*duration= total energy). This gives a nearly linear curve just in reverse of the power duration curve. How can this be done in swimming or running or similar? I have tried with average speed divided by cadence and this gives a quite linear curve, but units are kind of messed up. Any thoughts?

Cheers

Mikkel

Comment: Swimming will be very difficult due to the differences in form. You may have two athletes that have the exact same power and endurance, but one is 15% more efficient in form, that will throw off the curve. Somewhat the same in running.

Comment: Thank you. You are exactly right. I was mostly concerned with a curve just for the individual athlete. That way I could maybe detect deficiencies in aerobic/anaerobic capacity. Maybe form issues could be found as well I don't know, but right now I'm mostly curious about How to make the curve regardless of form for just a single athlete, testing multiple distances.